# Attempt to call global "Sicherheitskreis" (a nil value ) stack traceback

Tags: lua, mach

I'm trying to secure the doors of my CNC with switchs that send a Signal to my Laptop (I got Mach 4 on it). I created this Code that should make the Spindle stay still if the doors aren't locked, but I always get an error that says :

```
[string""]1576 attempt to call global 'SicherheitsKreis' (a Nil value) stack traceback:
```

I've tried to move the Code around and read topics on this, but Nothing works. 
Does someone have a solution ? 
Here's all my Code :

```
function SicherheitsKreis(Schliesserstate, Oeffnerstate)
   if (Schliesserstate ==0 and Oeffnerstate ==1 ) then 
     mc.mcSpindleSetDirection(inst,0)
   elseif (Schliesserstate == 1 and Oeffnerstate == 0 ) then 
     local sigh = mc.mcSignalGetHandle(inst, mc.OSIG_SPINDLEON);
     local sigState = mc.mcSignalGet State(sigh);
     if (sigState == 1) then 
       mc.mcSpindleSetDirection(inst,0)
     else 
       mc.mcSpindleSetDirection(inst,1);
     end
   else 
     mc.mcSpindleSetDirection(inst,0)
     end
end 

if (mc.mcInEditor() == 1) then
    SicherheitsKreis()
end
```

The Code that I'm using to call SicherheitsKreis is :

```
local inst = mc.mcGetInstance()
local hsigSchliesser = mc.mcSignalGetHandle(inst, mc.ISIG_INPUT8);
local hsigOeffner = mc.mcSignalGetHandle (inst, mc.ISIG_INPUT9);
local Schliesserstate = mc.mcSignalGetState(hsigSchliesser);
local Oeffnerstate = mc.mcSignalGetState(hsigSchliesser); 
 SicherheitsKreis(Schliesserstate, Oeffnerstate)
```

This Script is typed in Mach 4 and the function is saved as a m function (nach4 has free m function that the user can customize) in the Memory of Mach 4 (for my Computer it is m146)

Comment: Which line is #1576 ?

Comment: It can be that you call function before it is defined i.e. in initialization phase. Function `SicherheitsKreis` is called from the same script? Post the script part which calls `SicherheitsKreis`.

Comment: do not implement safety features in software. use safety relays that disconnect the spindle power if the door is opened.

Comment: I don't know what line #1576 is, it is some internal Mach 4 Code that I can't access.

Comment: What do you mean with safety relays ? I haven't seen something like this in the Lua script guide that I found for Mach 4. (Sorry if it's Clear to everyone but my english isn't really good)

Comment: it's not clear to me why you have two pieces of code with partially the same code. In one of them you have your SicherheitsKreis defined but in the other you try to use it, which of course fails because it isn't defined

Comment: Can you Elaborate when you say it is not defined ?  I don't want the function to return a value, I want it to use a Mach 4 function that turns the spindle on or off if the programm receives the good Signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
function SicherheitsKreis(Schliesserstate, Oeffnerstate)
...
end
```

First possibility is that code is in some other function or other element, so it is not global. Second possibility is that you run `SicherheitsKreis(Schliesserstate, Oeffnerstate)` before loading this part of code. Third (very uncommon) is that you override it by `SicherheitsKreis = nil` or equivalent.  There is no other possibilities.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694331/lua-attempt-to-call-global-a-nil-value